# IE8 in IE7-compatibility mode with extended CSS support

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

When IE8 is in IE7-compatibility mode it behabes like IE7 in quirks mode, which means there is no support for the new CSS features that IE7 supports (e.g. object selectors --child selectors, adjacent selectors, etc..).

How can I make IE8 to emulate IE7's standard mode rather than quirks mode??

---

**Note:**
The purpose of this is not to find out how will my page look under IE7. I have VMs with all major browser versions, so that's not a problem.
What I want is to make IE8 to interpret my pages in IE7-compatibility mode since they work well in the actual IE7's standard mode but they dont work well on IE8's standard mode nor IE8's quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IE8 Debug Toolbar to change document mode.

1. Hit F12 key to bring up IE Debug Toolbar.
2. Change **Browser Mode** to **IE 7**.
3. Change **Document Mode** to **Internet Explorer 7 Standards**.

This should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Just use browsershots for viewing site in any browser.](http://browsershots.org/)

Answer (score 0):

95% sure you can't. However, you can do what Sarfraz suggested, or perhaps download: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage  which will run pages with the actual engine (IE5, 5.5, 6, 7 ... ) to test your site.

Comment: I added a note to my question clearing that I dont need this for testing purposes